# google nest thermostat user and rate limits

Tags: lua, http-status-codes, nest-api, http-status-code-429, nest-device-access

I now have a project about smart air conditioners, hoping to control the central air conditioner through the nest thermostat. I hope that when the data of the nest thermostat changes, it can be monitored and fed back to the central air conditioner in a relatively short period of time, so I will get the data of the nest device every 3 seconds.

This is to get the API: https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/projectID/devices.
But it prompts 429 errors.

After checking the official documentation, I learned that Google API has a default user and rate limit (10/min), and you need to apply for business development to increase the limit. I tried to apply for business development many times, but there was no reply. I don’t know what to do next.

This is Google’s default limit:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnGuo.png)

how can I increase my limit? Or what can be done to achieve real-time data synchronization between the nest thermostat and the air conditioner (control within a few seconds)? If you can give me some suggestions or solutions, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

On average, thermostat data like humidity or temperature is probably not changing or fluctuating enough to warrant checking every 3 seconds.  You probably only need to check every minute or so and that way you won't hit the limit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. If I check the status of the thermostat at one minute intervals, it may take one minute for the central air conditioner to respond to the corresponding operation after operating the thermostat. I hope that the central air conditioner can respond in the shortest possible time (no more than 5s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to events: https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/subscribe-to-events

Ideally your app would only use the devices URL at startup.  Subsequently any changes in the traits would be received as events.  The API is definitely not supposed to be used for polling every few seconds.